# solving a simple advection equation (1D)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a 1D advection equation in Matlab as described in this [paper](http://mitran-lab.amath.unc.edu:8082/subversion/Papers/2011/VE_Entrain_JCP_Spec_Issue_MMS/biblio/LBM/LeeLin_JCP_2005_LBM_2Phase_HighDensViscRatio.pdf), equations (55)-(57). I am making use of the central difference in equaton (59).

I would ultimately like to get something like figure (2) in the paper, which is the result of solving the advection equation for an advection velocity e(1-k) with k=1, i.e. a stationary wave. However, my code keeps diverging. Here is what I have so far:

```
%initial parameters
    e  = 1.0;
    k  = 0.5;
    N  = 120;
    lx = 120;

  %initialization of sine
    for x=1:lx
        if(x<3*lx/4+1 && x>lx/4+1)
            phi(x) = sin(2*pi*(x-1-lx/4)/lx);
        else
            phi(x) = 0.0;
        end
    end


  %advection loop
    for t=1:N

        gradPhi = 0.5*(+circshift(phi, [0,-1]) - circshift(phi, [0,+1]));    
        phiBar  =  phi + 0.5*k*e*gradPhi;


        phiOutbar = circshift(phiBar, [0,-1]);

        gradPhi = 0.5*(+circshift(phiOutbar, [0,-1]) - circshift(phiOutbar, [0,+1]));
        phi     = phiOutbar + 0.5*k*e*gradPhi;
    end

    plot(phi)
```

Where is the error in my simple code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included the time step dt in your update equation. The term in equation (55) says k * e * dt / 2.
This is making your update really unstable and leading to divergence. For stability, you need [CFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition/) of 1, and yours is currently around 120. Try updating your code this way:

```
dt = 1/120;
%advection loop
for t=1:N/dt

    gradPhi = 0.5*(+circshift(phi, [0,-1]) - circshift(phi, [0,+1]));    
    phiBar  =  phi + 0.5*dt*k*e*gradPhi;


    phiOutbar = circshift(phiBar, [0,-1]);

    gradPhi = 0.5*(+circshift(phiOutbar, [0,-1]) - circshift(phiOutbar, [0,+1]));
    phi     = phiOutbar + 0.5*dt*k*e*gradPhi;
end
```